# python-docx install fails with pip

Tags: macos, python, pip

When I try to install python-docx with `sudo pip install python-docx` (or even without sudo), it always fails. I am not sure, but I think it might be because of a missing template since the last error is always `error: can't copy 'docx/templates/default-docx-template': doesn't exist or not a regular file`.

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-T_7KXe/python-docx/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-T_7KXe/python-docx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/tmp/pip-wheel-3WmEua --python-tag cp27
       cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-T_7KXe/python-docx/
  Complete output (107 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/docx
  copying docx/package.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/compat.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/blkcntnr.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/section.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/shared.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/api.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/document.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/settings.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/exceptions.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/shape.py -> build/lib/docx
  copying docx/table.py -> build/lib/docx
  creating build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/coreprops.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/simpletypes.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/ns.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/section.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/shared.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/numbering.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/document.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/styles.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/settings.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/exceptions.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/shape.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/table.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  copying docx/oxml/xmlchemy.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
  creating build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/package.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/coreprops.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/compat.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/oxml.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/constants.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/spec.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/shared.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/packuri.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/phys_pkg.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/exceptions.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/pkgreader.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/part.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/rel.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  copying docx/opc/pkgwriter.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
  creating build/lib/docx/dml
  copying docx/dml/color.py -> build/lib/docx/dml
  copying docx/dml/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/dml
  creating build/lib/docx/enum
  copying docx/enum/style.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
  copying docx/enum/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
  copying docx/enum/section.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
  copying docx/enum/text.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
  copying docx/enum/shape.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
  copying docx/enum/table.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
  copying docx/enum/dml.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
  copying docx/enum/base.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
  creating build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/tiff.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/gif.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/constants.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/jpeg.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/png.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/bmp.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/exceptions.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/helpers.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  copying docx/image/image.py -> build/lib/docx/image
  creating build/lib/docx/styles
  copying docx/styles/style.py -> build/lib/docx/styles
  copying docx/styles/latent.py -> build/lib/docx/styles
  copying docx/styles/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/styles
  copying docx/styles/styles.py -> build/lib/docx/styles
  creating build/lib/docx/parts
  copying docx/parts/story.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
  copying docx/parts/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
  copying docx/parts/numbering.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
  copying docx/parts/hdrftr.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
  copying docx/parts/document.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
  copying docx/parts/styles.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
  copying docx/parts/settings.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
  copying docx/parts/image.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
  creating build/lib/docx/text
  copying docx/text/run.py -> build/lib/docx/text
  copying docx/text/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/text
  copying docx/text/font.py -> build/lib/docx/text
  copying docx/text/tabstops.py -> build/lib/docx/text
  copying docx/text/parfmt.py -> build/lib/docx/text
  copying docx/text/paragraph.py -> build/lib/docx/text
  creating build/lib/docx/oxml/text
  copying docx/oxml/text/run.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
  copying docx/oxml/text/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
  copying docx/oxml/text/font.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
  copying docx/oxml/text/parfmt.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
  copying docx/oxml/text/paragraph.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
  creating build/lib/docx/opc/parts
  copying docx/opc/parts/coreprops.py -> build/lib/docx/opc/parts
  copying docx/opc/parts/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/opc/parts
  creating build/lib/docx/templates
  copying docx/templates/default-header.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
  copying docx/templates/default-settings.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
  copying docx/templates/default-footer.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
  error: can't copy 'docx/templates/default-docx-template': doesn't exist or not a regular file
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-docx
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-T_7KXe/python-docx/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-T_7KXe/python-docx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-AIkp8N/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-T_7KXe/python-docx/
    Complete output (107 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/docx
    copying docx/package.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/compat.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/blkcntnr.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/section.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/shared.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/api.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/document.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/settings.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/exceptions.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/shape.py -> build/lib/docx
    copying docx/table.py -> build/lib/docx
    creating build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/coreprops.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/simpletypes.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/ns.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/section.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/shared.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/numbering.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/document.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/styles.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/settings.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/exceptions.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/shape.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/table.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    copying docx/oxml/xmlchemy.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml
    creating build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/package.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/coreprops.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/compat.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/oxml.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/constants.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/spec.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/shared.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/packuri.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/phys_pkg.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/exceptions.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/pkgreader.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/part.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/rel.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    copying docx/opc/pkgwriter.py -> build/lib/docx/opc
    creating build/lib/docx/dml
    copying docx/dml/color.py -> build/lib/docx/dml
    copying docx/dml/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/dml
    creating build/lib/docx/enum
    copying docx/enum/style.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
    copying docx/enum/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
    copying docx/enum/section.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
    copying docx/enum/text.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
    copying docx/enum/shape.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
    copying docx/enum/table.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
    copying docx/enum/dml.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
    copying docx/enum/base.py -> build/lib/docx/enum
    creating build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/tiff.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/gif.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/constants.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/jpeg.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/png.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/bmp.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/exceptions.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/helpers.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    copying docx/image/image.py -> build/lib/docx/image
    creating build/lib/docx/styles
    copying docx/styles/style.py -> build/lib/docx/styles
    copying docx/styles/latent.py -> build/lib/docx/styles
    copying docx/styles/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/styles
    copying docx/styles/styles.py -> build/lib/docx/styles
    creating build/lib/docx/parts
    copying docx/parts/story.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
    copying docx/parts/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
    copying docx/parts/numbering.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
    copying docx/parts/hdrftr.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
    copying docx/parts/document.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
    copying docx/parts/styles.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
    copying docx/parts/settings.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
    copying docx/parts/image.py -> build/lib/docx/parts
    creating build/lib/docx/text
    copying docx/text/run.py -> build/lib/docx/text
    copying docx/text/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/text
    copying docx/text/font.py -> build/lib/docx/text
    copying docx/text/tabstops.py -> build/lib/docx/text
    copying docx/text/parfmt.py -> build/lib/docx/text
    copying docx/text/paragraph.py -> build/lib/docx/text
    creating build/lib/docx/oxml/text
    copying docx/oxml/text/run.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
    copying docx/oxml/text/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
    copying docx/oxml/text/font.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
    copying docx/oxml/text/parfmt.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
    copying docx/oxml/text/paragraph.py -> build/lib/docx/oxml/text
    creating build/lib/docx/opc/parts
    copying docx/opc/parts/coreprops.py -> build/lib/docx/opc/parts
    copying docx/opc/parts/__init__.py -> build/lib/docx/opc/parts
    creating build/lib/docx/templates
    copying docx/templates/default-header.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
    copying docx/templates/default-settings.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
    copying docx/templates/default-footer.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
    error: can't copy 'docx/templates/default-docx-template': doesn't exist or not a regular file
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-T_7KXe/python-docx/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-T_7KXe/python-docx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-AIkp8N/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was a problem with the source, I downloaded the source and removed the folder `docx/templates/default-docx-template`, then installed it with `pip install .`. Seems the installer expected only files as templates...